# Получить значение дата атрибута

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

В цикле php выводятся блоки. Нужно получить дата атрибут и передать его переменной php пробую так:

```
<span onClick ="getdetails()" class="compare-button with-tip " data-room="<?=$id_room?>"></span>
<script>
function getdetails(){
event.preventDefault();
  var id_room = $(this).data("room") ;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
         url: 'add.php',
        data: {id_room:id_room}
      
    }).done(function( result )
        {
          console.log('Ответ получен');
          console.log(result);
        });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте ещё как вариант

```js
$(this).attr("data-room");
```

В моей практике этот способ зарекомендовал себя более надёжным, чем `data`

Comment: на сервере так принимать нужно $id_room=$_POST['id_room'];?

Comment: @Nick var_dump($_POST) посмотри

Comment: @Jean-Claude array(0) { } в переменной id_room undefined

Comment: пошлите сначала себе в явном виде число в room_id, оно показывается, или тоже нет?

Comment: @AlexKhonko не показывается

Comment: в инете(и даже на ютубе) куча примеров с PHP + ajax. Выполните по примеру, и потом перенесите себе

Comment: @Nick если в $_POST ничего нет, возможно неправильные пути пишешь к add.php (при условии что в консоли не пишет ошибок в js)